# Solving this trigonometric summation: $\sum_{i=1}^{88}{\frac{1}{\cos i°\cdot cos(i+1)°}}$

Tags: trigonometry, summation

How would we solve this summation?

$$\sum_{i=1}^{88}{\frac{1}{\cos i°\cdot \cos(i+1)°}}$$

I can't seem to make a start anywhere...

Comment: Possible starts: the sum-to-product formula or the complex exponential representation of the cosine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\sum_{i=1}^{88}{\frac{1}{\cos i° \times \cos(i+1)°}} = \frac{1}{\sin(1°)}\sum_{i=1}^{88}{\frac{\sin((i+1) - (i))°}{\cos i° \times \cos(i+1)°}} = \frac{1}{\sin(1°)}\sum_{i=1}^{88}{\frac{\sin(i+1)°\cos(i°) - \cos(i+1)°\sin(i°)}{\cos i° \times \cos(i+1)°}} = \frac{1}{\sin(1°)}\sum_{i=1}^{88}{\tan(i+1)° - \tan(i)°} = \frac{\tan(89°) - \tan(1°)}{\sin(1°)}$

Comment: Thanks! I love the answer's simplicity and elegance

Answer (score 2):

Since:
$$
\frac{\sin \beta}{\cos(\alpha+i\beta)\cos(\alpha+(i+1)\beta)}=\tan(\alpha+(i+1)\beta)-\tan(\alpha+i\beta)
$$
The following identity holds given all denominators a non-zero:
$$
\sum_{i=1}^{k}\frac{1}{\cos(\alpha+i\beta)\cos(\alpha+(i+1)\beta)}=\frac{\tan(\alpha+(k+1)\beta)-\tan(\alpha+\beta)}{\sin \beta}
$$